# Disqus Password Credentials OAuth

Tags: ios, oauth, disqus

I'm trying to authenticate a user in my iOS app but all I get is a **400 error**.

According to the [documentation](http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/), *"this type of flow is restricted to approved applications only, so you **must request access first**"*.

So how do I approve my application to be able to accomplish this flow?

Part of my request:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:WS_TIMEOUT];

NSString *strAuth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
NSString *strAuthBase64 = [[strAuth dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"grant_type=password&client_secret=%@&client_id=%@&scope=read,write", DISQUS_SECRET, DISQUS_KEY];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", strAuthBase64] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something we'd have to enable for your application from our end. However, I'd instead recommend hosting a page to handle the authentication with the standard server-side flow. You can then pull the access token and other variables from the page into your application after the user has authorized.

The reason is so you don't have to deal with form validation, error messaging, and can take advantage of our updates to the form without touching your code.

Some server-side OAuth examples in PHP and Python can be found on this page: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/oauth

Answer (score 2):

Try this library which solves Disqus authorization issue in a slick manner. Really nice solution https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios